# Pointer to data that stored in a map container

Tags: c++, pointers, stl, dictionary

I have 2 map one of them contain data

for example

```
struct DATA {
  int A1;
  int A2;
};
typedef map<int,DATA> DataList;
DataList myData;
```

I have also tried some of the following: 
      `typedef  map<int,DATA*??> DataListPointer;` 
      `table<col_name,DataListPointer>;`

(Note: CC: I really do not get this line:

> map is a table. list of  column and pointer to data that exist on `myData`.

or what table is doing in the above
).

but i would like to know how to get to a pointer to data that exist in a map. How I can do it?
thanks herzl.

Comment: Can you give a concrete example of what you want to do?

Comment: my data exist a in a class and I don't want copy it to other scope. I want only send the table structure that point to the data.

Comment: @closers I think there's a reasonable question in there somewhere, just in need of some editing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gets a pointer to a DATA value in the map, if present.

```
   DataList::iterator it = myData.find( 42 );
   DATA * pData = NULL;       
   if ( it != myData.end() ) {
          pData = &((*it).second);
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

You might want 2 overloads:

```
DATA * lookup( DataList & theMap, int key )
{
   DataList::iterator iter = theMap.find( key );
   if( iter != theMap.end() )
   {
      return &iter->second;
   }
   else
     return NULL;
}
```

and

```
const DATA * lookup( const DataList & theMap, int key )
{
   DataList::const_iterator iter = theMap.find( key );
   if( iter != theMap.end() )
   {
      return &iter->second;
   }
   else
     return NULL;
}
```

Of course this means duplicating code. So may be a good candidate to const-cast.

```
DATA * lookup( DataList & theMap, int key )
{
   return const_cast<DATA *>(lookup( const_cast<const DataList&>(theMap), key));
}
```

and you could make it a generic template:

```
template< typename Key, typename Value >
const Value * mapValueLookup( const std::map<Key, Value>& theMap, Key key )
{
   typename std::map<Key, Value>::const_iterator iter = theMap.find(key);
   if( iter != theMap.end() )
   {
      return &iter->second;
   }
   else
     return NULL;
}

template< typename Key, typename Value >
Value * mapValueLookup( std::map<Key, Value>& theMap, Key key )
{
   return const_cast<Value*>( mapValueLookup
       ( const_cast<const std::map<Key, Value> &>(theMap),
       key ) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your definitions (which are perfectly adequate), as has been pointed out already, your map is made up of `std::pair<int, DATA>` elements, strung together somehow (red-black tree, generally, for ordered `std::map`). An iterator gives you a position in that map and behaves like a pointer to an element. In particular, dereferencing a valid one gives the `std::pair` with your key in `.first` and your data in `.second`. Instead of `nullptr`, though, you have `map.end()` acting as the "no valid content" iterator value. So `map.find(key)` gives you the iterator holding the position of the pair whose `.first` equals your `key`, if found, or the iterator value `map.end()` otherwise.

The previous posts provide good solutions. I think the minimalist generic solution would look like this:

```
// return a pointer to the map's mapped_type value associated with the key;
// if the key is not found, return nullptr.
template <class Map, typename Key>
auto mapLookup(Map&& map, Key&& key)
{
  auto iter = map.find(key);
  return iter != map.end() ? &iter->second : nullptr;
}
```

which works for both mutable and constant maps.

So, if you have the following:

```
DataList myData;
//...
myData[1] = DATA{ 2, 3 };
//...
```

you can do

```
DATA* pointer1 = mapLookup(myData, 1);
assert (pointer1 != nullptr); // we expect to find myData
assert (pointer1 == &myData[1]); // it should be the same as indexed access
assert (pointer1->A1 == 2); // and should find the values we inserted
assert (pointer1->A2 == 3);

DATA* pointer2 = mapLookup(myData, 999); // a key we haven't used
assert (pointer2 == nullptr); // so we could not find it
```

It's a shame that this functionality is not immediately available in the standard (non-multi) map types. C++20 adds a `bool contains(const Key& key) const` method, which is nice, but if it had returned a pointer to the value (or a `std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<mapped_type>>>`?) it would have allowed the same functionality (you can test a pointer's null-ness with `!` just like a `bool`) as well as providing immediate access to the data if it's there.